# Dialog Helper class how to call

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I would like to ask for advice here, I want to create a dialog for a sign out box, because this box can be called from almost every screen, I want to create a new class which include this method and the call it every time the button is clicked, but honestly I don't know how to do it, I've created a class called SignOutHelper

```
public class SignOutHelper extends Activity {

public Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("do you wish to sign out?");
    builder.setTitle("Sign Out");

    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();   
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

now I want to call this class from a normal activity but I don't know how to do it, I'll appreciate your help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make static method to create Dialog.

```
public class SignOutHelper {

public static Dialog CreateDialog(Context c) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    builder.setMessage("do you wish to sign out?");
    builder.setTitle("Sign Out");

    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();   
    return builder.create();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I call that method from my main activity?

Comment: `SignOutHelper.CreateDialog(this).show();` or `SignOutHelper.CreateDialog(MainActivity.this).show();`

Comment: How would you dismiss/cancel this dialog in order to prevent Window leak when device rotates?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. create a static method in your helper class and just call the method in your button click.

**SignOutHelper.java**

```
public class SignOutHelper {

    public static void showDialog(Context con){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
        builder.setMessage("do you wish to sign out?");
        builder.setTitle("Sign Out");

        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Call the method in your button click like this.

In your Activity file,

```
Button dialogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       SignOutHelper.showDialog(MainActivity.this); 
       }
});
```

That's it.. cheers!

Comment: Hi, I am getting an exception android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application , any idea why?

Comment: I changed the context in the above code. This code will work now.
getApplicationContext() is changed to "MainActivity.this".  @Juancadiyjohndiy